# JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{ Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I don't understand. Is it the double quotes? I'm trying to import from a json file into my database.

```
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Backcountry Skiing",
  "keywords_list": null,
  "keywords": [
```

Here is my rake task:

```
require 'json'

namespace :fieldfacts do
  desc "Import Topics"
  task :import_topics => :environment do
    records = JSON.parse(File.read('public/topics.json').gsub('\"', '"'))
    records.each do |record|
      a = Topic.new
      a.name = record['name']
      a.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like invalid JSON.

Comment: validate json here http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

You can covert this string to hash using `eval` like this:

```
eval(hash_string)
```

What you have is JSON string that's why it was raising error.

Note: Just be careful using eval because it can inject malicious code inside your system depending upon where your hash come from.